How to Calculate Probabilities for a Causal Graph?
I was reading a paper on causal inference. In this paper I came up with this causal graph
In this causal graph, if we ignore E (Environment variable), and consider all variables are binary for simplicity. Now, we assume $p_{x_1}(1) = 0.5$, and
$$p_{y|x_1}(1|1) = p_{y|x_1}(0|0) = 0.9 \tag{1}$$
Which makes $X_1$ a good predictor for $Y$. Next we define the conditional prior of $X_2$ as
$$ p_{x_2|y}(1|1) = p_{x_2|y}(0|0) = 0.9 $$
According to the Bayes rule,
$$p_{y|x_2}(1|1) = p_{y|x_2}(0|0) = 0.9 \tag{2}$$
Which makes $X_2$ also a good predictor for $Y$. Finally assume the conditional prior of $X_3$ is
$$p_{x_3|x_1,x_2}(1|1,1) = p_{x_3|x_1,x_2}(0|0,0) = 1; \text{and} $$
$$p_{x_3|x_1,x_2}(1|0,1) = p_{x_3|x_1,x_2}(1|1,0) = 0.5. $$
It can be computed that:
\begin{equation}
p_{x_3|y}(1|1) = p_{x_3|y}(0|0) = 0.9 \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Hence the predictive power of $X_3$ is also the same as $X_1$ and $X_2$.
In this above problem, I understand the equations (1) and (2). I am also able to derive them. But my key problem with equation (3). I tried to derive the equation (3), but I fail to do it. I am not able to understand what probability rule the authors use to derive the equation (3). In the original paper, they just say we can compute the equation (3) using the conditional prior of $X_3$.
I would highly appreciate if anyone could help me to derive the equation (3).
